# Margin causes 100% height to give horizontal scrollbars

Tags: html, css

It's been a while since I handcoded a website, and now I have the issue that my top-margin causes the 100% height to give a nasty scrollbar, as seen in the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qKGzA/

I can't figure out how to get rid of this, without cutting off the footer (like with using overflow:hidden).
It probably is a simple solution but I can't think of it :)

Thanks for your help!

My code:

```
 html, body{
    background-color:#ececec;

    height:100%;
    width: 100%;

    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

div#wrapper{
    background-color:#ffffff;

    width: 962px;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;

    margin:0 auto;
    padding:20px 15px 0px 15px;

    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

footer{
    background-color:#363636;

    width:95%;
    height: 15px;

    margin:0;
    padding:10px;

    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;

    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#e1e1e1;
    text-align:center;
}

footer p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
footer p.divider{
    margin:0 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <body>


<div id="wrapper" >
    <header>
    header header
    </header>
    <menu> Menu menu</menu>
    <section>
    section section
    </section>
    <footer>
    <p>x</p><p class="divider">~</p>
    <p>x</p><p class="divider">~</p>
    <p>x</p><p class="divider">~</p>
    <p>x</p>
    </footer>
</div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div#wrapper has height:100% and padding:20px 15px 0px 15px making it 100% + 20 pixels.  if you add

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

to div#wrapper the padding will be inside the 100%, and the scroll bars disappear.

A non-css3 alternative is to place an element at the top of the inside of the div#wrapper with a height of 20 pixels. Perhaps add the 20px top padding to the header element which is inside the wrapper for non CSS3 browsers.

Answer (score 1):

a.  Does your body have to have the height and width assigned?  Couldn't you simply set the background.  It should automatically span any width non-dependent on the user's screen.

b.  You could set the body to position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; overflow: hidden;
This should allow your body to expand in height as needed.

c.  You could assign an actual height in pixels, or em . Something like 700px should not go off the screen, but of course that would change if the user is mobile.

Comment: A combo of your and Wayne's answer worked: Body with position absolute and the box-sizing:border-box to the #wrapper :) 
Thanks!

Comment: Now I've got another issue: The width of the footer is too wide (the 100% goes over the wrapper width, which I don't want). My code is like this (only it doesnt show right in the fiddle. I work in Chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/qKGzA/1/
Removing the position:absolute & bottom:0 fixes that problem, but then the footer isn't at the bottom of the page..